# rotation of punctured half plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

So I was trying to find $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash L \cup  S^1)$ where L is a line disjoint from $S^1$ but L passes through the disk $D^2$ bounded by $S^1$. I don't know if there is an easier way to do this, but one way is seeing 
 $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash (L \cup S^1)$ as the rotation of the punctured open half plane  $$Y=\{ (x,y,z)\mid z=0,x>0\}\setminus \{(1,0,0)\}.$$

Thus $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash L \cup S^1 = S^1 \times Y$.

I have trouble visualizing why this is true. It doesn't have to be an analytic proof but maybe some way to see this.

Answer (score 1):

To see why the rotation $R(Y)$ of the punctured open half plane looks like $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus (L \cup S^1)$ as you describe, notice that $R(Y)$ is missing the line $L = \{(0,y,0)\ |\ y\in \mathbb{R}$}, as well as the circle $S$ given by rotating the point $\{(1,0,0)\}$ in the $xz$-plane. The circle $S$ and the line $L$ are disjoint, and $S$ bounds the unit disk in the $xz$-plane which contains $(0,0,0)$ and hence intersects $L$.

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite see it. Why if we remove a circle and a line from $\mathbb{R}^3$ it is the same as rotating the punctured half plane Y above?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought the question was just to compute the fundamental group. I will edit my answer

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I will try to absorb this. It looks logical.